# Writing Excel Formulas with Row and Column Numbers instead of Cell Address Python

Tags: python, excel, pandas, xlsxwriter

I currently have the following code:

```
revenue_stats_feb = pd.DataFrame({'February' :['=D7/D40','=D7/D39','=D7/D37','=D7/D11','=D8/D7', '=D10/D8'],
                                  'merge': [1,2,3,4,5,6]})
    revenue_stats_feb = revenue_stats_feb[['February', 'merge']]
```

I was wondering if it is possible to write the formulas using the row and column numbers instead of the cell address, i.e. '=D7/D40' would be '=(3,6)/(3,39)' but when it gets exported to excel it still calculates as D7/D40 would.

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: Excel needs D7/D40, why would you do this?

Comment: Because depending on the month, D40 could change to be either D39 or D41 etc, so I want to try and automate it by using len(def.index) to assign the row that should be the divisor.

Comment: You might be able to use R1C1 (row, column) format to specify cell values combined with the INDIRECT function.  In Calc, "=INDIRECT("R3C2", 0)" gets the value of cell B3.  Should be similar in Excel.  Or maybe the CELLS function?  My Excel skills are a bit rusty.

Comment: @b2002 that is a great idea and it works for exactly what I need. The code I am using now looks like this '=C7/INDIRECT("R{}C3",0)'.format((len(output_df.index) + 3 + len(practice_locations.index)))

Comment: r1c1 allows you to just omit the number if it's the same, so if you want to point to another column in the same row, it'll be `rc__` and if it's the same column but different row it'll just be `r__c`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way would be to use the functions XlsxWriter provides to convert `(row, col)` values to strings:

```
from xlsxwriter.utility import xl_rowcol_to_cell

formula = '=%s/%s' % (xl_rowcol_to_cell(6,  3),
                      xl_rowcol_to_cell(39, 3))

print(formula)  # =D7/D40
```

See the [Working with Cell Notation](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_cell_notation.html) section of the XlsxWriter docs for more details.